# Hide options in Vimeo video

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, vimeo

Can we hide only the options like title,logo, like and watch on the Vimeo video except play/pause?
Tried with css/javascript but couldn't hide the options on the video as the video is inside an iframe.

Tried with background="true" but all the player toggles and element are turned off (including the play/pause button)

Is there any API which can be used to hide the options on the vimeo video?
Can this be achieved using Javascipt/Java?

Comment: hi, please add some example showing what you have done so far, and where it fails

Comment: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224972808-Customizing-the-embedded-player

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate question states: `Can we hide only the options like title,logo, like and watch on the Vimeo video except play/pause?`

Title, byline and portrait can be hidden by adding those parameters onto the URL or in the options when initializing the player. All the options can be seen [here in the Vimeo player repo](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#embed-options). For example:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?byline=0&portrait=0&title=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Or by modifying [this example](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#create-with-a-video-id-or-url) with the right options :

```
    var options = {
      id: 59777392,
      width: 640,
      byline: false,
      portrait: false,
      title: false
    };
```

It is CRITICAL to note that these will only work if the videos owner allowed for this in their Video settings page by selecting the `Let Users Decide` option in the "Your Details" section of the settings page.

The Logo, watch later, and like buttons can only be turned off in the settings page by the video owner as well.

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Share this video` will open a modal window

[image: Step 1]

here u can click on `show options` which is next to **Embed**, there u can find few option checkbox to hide `title, logo` and other things of the vimeo video.

[image: Step 2]